# how can i use jquery mobile in a div container and prevent the style effects outside this div?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css, jquery-mobile

currently i have div container with data-role='page' and few inner div with data-role='fieldcontain'.
under the (div data-role='page' ) I have few buttons and elements effected from jquery mobile style .how can I prevent this behave?

```
<div>
    <div data-role='page' >
        <div data-role='fieldcontain'>....</div>
    </div>

    <div><button id="btn1"></button>....</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `data-role="none"` like in native forms to prevent button styling:

```
<button id="btn1" data-role="none">Button element</button>
```

or you have to define your own theme (without the structural CSS) with for example:

```
<button id="btn1" data-theme="e"></button>
```

Otherwise I don't think this is possible since jQuery is meant to 'update' the whole page.

**See also:**
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/forms/forms-all-native.html

**Sample:**
http://jsfiddle.net/X83rh/

Comment: Thanks for the answer,
in this example the button is in the div data-role='page' and if I am get it out this div it disappear.any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @the_farmer you cannot have content outside the page. You have to show it on the page or another page, but all content has to be within a page.